# htaccess rewrite to always have www in subfolders?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is it possible to edit a htaccess to always use www in a certain subfolder? I've found the option to do it for whole directories, but I can't find any way of doing it for a sub directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this rule in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(folder1|folder2)/ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE,NC]
```

This will only affect `folder1` and `folder2` for adding `www` in domain name.

Comment: I had to wait a few hours unfortunately. I've just got back and have done so.